# Number of Voyager Crew exceeded?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, behind-the-scenes

Has anyone ever counted, by checking all the episodes, how many extras of the crew have shown up on screen to see if it exceeds the 150 crew Voyager is supposed to have?

Comment: I mean, _someone_ has, sure.

Comment: I remember reading 10+ years ago on a german fansite that somebody did a count, and it easily exceeded the number, if only for the practical reasons that tracking and planning in every random background-extra would be a huge amount of work that barely anybody would appreciate or notice

Comment: @matthias_code I imagine this might be the German fansite you're thinking of: https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/voyager-crew.htm

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 Yes, that's it! :D Oh wow, they even have a detailed breakdown now

Comment: Not what you're asking, but on tor.com they've been having a rewatch of all the Voyager episodes in order, and the reviewer regularly notes that they are completely inconsistent with the numbers not taking into account all the people that have been killed over the years.

Comment: You mean, like someone did for [photon torpedoes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIGxMENwq1k)?

Comment: Thank you for that website, if only because it showed me the list of killed crew members that includes: Commander J. Bartlett, Lieutenant Commander L. McGarry, Lieutenant Commander T. Ziegler, Lieutenant J. Lyman, Lieutenant S. Seaborn, Ensign Claudia J. Craig, Ensign Charles Young.

Answer (score 3):

In a word, yes. The website Memory-Alpha has a nice section related to unnamed crew members seen on board the USS Voyager during its trip through the Delta and Beta Quadrants on its way home. A quick headcount reveals that the number of (unnamed) extras exceeds 200.

- [Unnamed USS Voyager personnel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_USS_Voyager_personnel)
- [Unnamed USS Voyager command division personnel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_USS_Voyager_command_division_personnel)
- [Unnamed USS Voyager operations division personnel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_USS_Voyager_operations_division_personnel)
- [Unnamed USS Voyager sciences division personnel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_USS_Voyager_sciences_division_personnel)

This is in addition to the 231 members of [named crew](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Voyager_personnel), bringing the **total complement to over 430** (and more than 450 if you also include voice-only characters, and nearly 500 if you also include those [referred to as being killed off-screen](https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/voyager-crew.htm)).

Comment: It's like the proverbial Western movie pistol that never runs out of ammunition.

Comment: @Spencer - Willing suspension of disbelief.

Comment: It seems like obviously some of the unnamed crew and mentioned crew and voice-only crew could be easily be the same people.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Oh sure. And I'll happily admit that there's likely to be some overlap, especially when trying to identify people from different angles.

Comment: But where's the fun in admitting that?

Comment: @FreeMan - I think the fact that just the *named* characters exceed the stated crew complement is proof-positive that the makers just didn't care.

Comment: @Valorum:   It's the future.  Who's to say people aren't changing their names, appearances, and species whenever they want.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Maybe they're all secret time travellers.

Comment: @Valorum:   Actually, they are all the same person and that person is their own father and mother.